# Get only data from the last month (in January)

Tags: sql

I have been using Month(Getdate())-1 for the past few months and it was working great. Now in January it is not working. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please show your complete query and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: yes we need to see the code. Also -1 equals 0 in January...

Comment: `SELECT
   "End Date",
   "BP Code",
   "Amount"
FROM  "Source_DB (SB)" LEFT JOIN "steering_database" ON "steering_database"."date"  = "Source_DB (SB)"."end date"
  AND "steering_database"."bp code"  = "Source_DB (SB)"."bp code"  
WHERE  "steering_database"."source indicator"  = 'Total number of impacted customers:'
 AND MONTH("End Date")  = (MONTH(GETDATE()) -1)`

I am using Zoho Reports, not sure what they use exactly. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you get last month by doing:

```
dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
```

Assuming you have a date column, you would get last months data by doing something like:

```
where month(datecol) = month( dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) ) and
      year(datecol) = year( dateadd(month, -1, getdate()) )
```

If `month` and `year` are in separate columns, then you can modify appropriately.

Note:  There are many other ways to do this calculation.  This is just showing a reasonable way given the information in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but unfortunately this is now working for me. Please check my comment above, I added the code.